# Convert ->numrows for use with DBD::mysql in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, dbd

I have some old code that uses the old `Mysql` library in Perl.

Most of the time updating the code to use `DBD::mysql` instead works with no problems however I have run into an issue where `->numrows` does not work.

What should I do to get the same functionality whilst using `DBD::mysql`

**use Mysql**

```
use Mysql;

$type = "yellow";

$statement = "select name from customer where type = '$type'";

$sth = $dbh->query($statement);

if ($sth->numrows) {
  print "Success!"; # This does work.
}
```

**use DBD::mysql**

```
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

$type = "yellow";

$statement = "select name from customer where type = ?";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
$sth->execute($type);

if ($sth->numrows) {
  print "Success!"; # This doesn't work.
}
```

This is the error I get back:

**tail /var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
 Can't locate object method "numrows" via package "DBI::st"
```

Comment: From [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI): For SELECT statements, execute simply "starts" the query within the database engine. Use one of the fetch methods to retrieve the data after calling execute. The execute method does not return the number of rows that will be returned by the query (because most databases can't tell in advance), it simply returns a true value.

Comment: `$sth->execute($type); $numRows = $sth->rows; if ($numRows) { print "Success!";}` This should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use it as below

```
if ($sth->rows)
```